# Control-M batch job started throwing an error after Service account password getting changed

Tags: server, windows-server-2003, control-m

I am facing a very common issue may be, but I am not able to figure it out.
Someone has reset the password for service account from the back end (on which control-m job was placed).Now, I am getting the password was not correct error on the Control-M.

Question that arise in my mind:
1)I haven't used service account with password before. Also, I haven't configured password anywhere while creating the batch-job.
2)Do I have to update the password on back-end? if yes, where to update and how?

I am new to windows server 2003 (old machine).Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I come to know that CONTROL-M itself storing the passwords!!!! yes, you've heard it correctly.

you will find the file called **PASSWRDS.dat** at the below location (location may vary)

```
 C:\Program Files\BMC Software\Control-M Agent\Default\DATA
```

Open this file. it will contain your service account and password in hashed format as below:

```
SERVICE_ACCT_USER
00-134570-410-2800123493493232323-234234A123-JSHASAWQQ
```

you will not be able to understand what is the actual password as it will be hashed using multiple algorithms.

How to cope up with the issue??

1) erase service account and password from the passwrds.dat file

2) Open command prompt and change the location to **C:\Program Files\BMC Software\Control-M Agent\Default\EXE**

3) run below command

```
ctmpwd -action add -user yourserviceaccountuse -password serviceaccountpwd
```

that's it. 
In future, if you change the password, make sure to follow the same procedure.